# Wrapper class in java

Tags: java

What is the use of wrapper class? I can't understand the wrapping thing in this topic. It wraps primitive data types but for what and how it wraps? When they tell wrapping what does it really mean?

Comment: Which 'this' topic are you talking about? please provide more details.

Comment: I love how he jumped into the subject :) Even though I am still trying to understand what he is talking about :) What kind of Wrapper Class :)

Comment: I am new to this topic. I googled but still not able to understand. sorry that i m not able to be more specific on the question!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921208/about-wrapper-class

Comment: Maybe you can provide a link to what you were reading and which part you couldn't understand?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you are aware, In Java not everything is an Object. There are primitive types such as int ,double float etc. So if you wanted to use a primitive type in place of Object i.e. if a method expects an Object but you need to send in a primitive type, without Wrapper classes this wouldn't be possible. Take for instance the Map interface. The `put(Object,Object)` method takes Objects as both key and value. If you, for example wanted to store a mapping between an integer value 1 (`int i=1`) to an Object, without wrapper classes this wouldn't be possible. Wrapper classes are used to represent primitive values when an object is required.

Answer (score 4):

The general idea of a wrapper class is a class that, for lack of a better term, 'boxes' another class or some other functionality. This could be done to abstract the wrapped items, and expose a simpler interface to the user.

I think your specific question concerns the [Java Primitive Wrapper Classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class), which are classes that represent the primitive types (`int`, `double`, `boolean`, `byte`, and so on) as classes. One of the reasons for this is they are used for when `Object` types are needed and you want to use primitives, like when using any class in `java.Collections`.

Answer (score 0):

According to what Wikipedia says to my question ["What is a wrapper class in Java"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class):

> A primitive wrapper class in the Java programming language is one of
>   eight classes provided in the java.lang package to provide object
>   methods for the eight primitive types. All of the primitive wrapper
>   classes in Java are immutable. J2SE 5.0 introduced autoboxing of
>   primitive types into their wrapper object, and automatic unboxing of
>   the wrapper objects into their primitive value—the implicit conversion
>   between the wrapper objects and primitive values.
>
> Wrapper classes are used to represent primitive values when an Object
>   is required. The wrapper classes are used extensively with Collection
>   classes in the java.util package and with the classes in the
>   java.lang.reflect reflection package.